# Ifz, ipx bsf zpv epjoh Wbooz? What does this code from my mother's highschool stuff say?

Tags: cipher

I found this code in my mother's box of highschool stuff when we were cleaning the basement and found this just wondering what it says

Ifz, ipx bsf zpv epjoh Wbooz?

J bn epjoh xfmm, zpv?

J bn epjoh xfmm bmtp cvu zpv lopx Ftnf sjhiu?

Ivi?

Nz ebvhiufs? Nz gjstucpso ebvhiufs boe tfdpoe dijme?

Pi zfbi, J sfnfncfs opx...xibu bcpvu ifs?

Xfmm, tif xbt sfcpso, cvu gjstu, tif cfdbnf bo bohfm uifo xifo tif ejfe boe tif qpttfttfe Ojhiunbsjpoof, uifo, bmm uif puifst.

Pi, xibut uif qspcmfn?

Tif xbout up svo bxbz gspn ifs sfcpso gbnjmz cvu tif bmtp epfto'u xbou up cfdbvtf tif epfto'u lopx xifsf xf bsf.

Xiz epo'u zpv kvtu hp hfu ifs, boe ipx ep zpv lopx bmm pg uijt?

1. cfdbvtf J dbo'u esjwf cfdbvtf pg nz qipcjb boe Xjmmjbn xpo'u xbou up cfdbvtf if jt bgsbje tif xjmm ibuf ijn bgufs xibu if eje jo uif qbtu boe 2. cfdbvtf J btlfe Mpmcju, Ojhiunbsjpoof, boe Fdlp up mjtufo xifo tif jt ubmljoh bcpvu ju.

Pi, zfbi zpvs qipcjb, boe bmtp epo'u zpv uijol jg Ftnf gjoet pvu tif xjmm btl uifn xip upme uifn uifz dpvme ep uibu. Bmtp, Fdlp dbo'u mjf tif xjmm hfu tipdlfe ju jt jo ifs qsphsbnnjoh gps tpnf pee sfbtpo tp tif xjmm ibwf up ufmm Ftnf.

Pi zfbi, pi xfmm uifz bsf cfjoh dbsfgvm.

Pl xfmm jg zpv, Xjmmjbn, Mjaaz, Disjt, ps Njdibfm offe bozuijoh kvtu mfu Wjodfou ps J lopx.

J bmxbzt xjmm Wbooz.

Xf bsf gbnjmz.

Zft, xf bsf.

Jg bozuijoh ibqqfot bcpvu Ftnf boe zpv offe up hfu ifs mfu nf lopx boe J xjmm hp hfu ifs.

Pl, mpwf zpv, Wbooz.

Mpwf zpv upp Dmbsb.

Comment: @ThatAnimePerson, welcome to the site! The downvotes on this puzzle are probably due to 1) a perceived lack of effort (basic Caesar shifts are one of the most common cipher techniques, so not checking for that beforehand is seen as lacking effort) and 2) being rude to people trying to help you in (deleted) comments under Jafe's answer. This is an established community, and new users are expected to be polite (experienced users are also expected to be polite!) and make at least some effort to understand the site culture/rules. Better luck with your next question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your apparent issue... I went to rot13.com, copied in your text, and used ROT25 to get this:

> Hey, how are you doing Vanny?
> I am doing well, you?
> I am doing well also but you know Esme right?
> Huh?
> My daughter? My firstborn daughter and second child?
> Oh yeah, I remember now...what about her?
> Well, she was reborn, but first, she became an angel then when she died and she possessed Nightmarionne, then, all the others.
> Oh, whats the problem?
> She wants to run away from her reborn family but she also doesn't want to because she doesn't know where we are.
> Why don't you just go get her, and how do you know all of this?
> 1. because I can't drive because of my phobia and William won't want to because he is afraid she will hate him after what he did in the past and 2. because I asked Lolbit, Nightmarionne, and Ecko to listen when she is talking about it.
> Oh, yeah your phobia, and also don't you think if Esme finds out she will ask them who told them they could do that. Also, Ecko can't lie she will get shocked it is in her programming for some odd reason so she will have to tell Esme.
> Oh yeah, oh well they are being careful.
> Ok well if you, William, Lizzy, Chris, or Michael need anything just let Vincent or I know.
> I always will Vanny.
> We are family.
> Yes, we are.
> If anything happens about Esme and you need to get her let me know and I will go get her.
> Ok, love you, Vanny.
> Love you too Clara.

Note that this took way more time and effort for me to format a response post than to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Thank you for answering I will ask my Mom what she knows...and there are a lot more so I will probably be posting more soon but still thank you so much for the Correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Try moving each letter one step backward in the alphabet.